# Drop all tables at hibernate startup

Tags: java, hibernate

How can I configure hibernate in a way that it DROPS all tables before it runs, for developement purposes? I don't want to constantly DROP all tables by hand before running my code.

I'm already using

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

But this does not seem to work, since I ran into several errors that where caused by wrong schemas from a previous run.

**Edit**
Maybe my questions was a bit missleading. I want to have a clean database. Its not only because of actual runtime errors but also about having a clean database for every run.

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>
```

Ignores tables that are unknown to hibernate (which can happen quite often if you are playing around with tablenames).

Comment: create-drop is the way to go. If you make significant changes to the data model (eg removed/renamed some entities) clear the database it by hand. I think that it will take less of your time to do so as it will be rather rare, then time that will take to find out of the box solutios that suits your use case scenario.

Comment: in application.properties: spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop

Answer (score 5):

Use the value `create-drop` instead of `create`

Comment: Take care when using this configuration in a non development enviroment.

Comment: But this will not drop tables that are no longer known for hibernate since I have renamed them. Is there no way to simply drop all tables in the database?

Comment: Not directly using hibernate.  Hibernate by intent will only attempt to manipulate objects that it knows about.  On the other hand, it would be possible to create native SQL commands using a hibernate connection that query the database metadata (such as INFORMATION_SCHEMA) and execute native table drops.

Comment: This will drop tables which were created AFTER the test, but the question is asking BEFORE, other tables will remain in DB.  I would like to know how to start tests in clean database but keep the data after the test for manual examination

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility to get an always clean database at startup in a development environment is  an in memory db like H2 or similar. See http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#in_memory_databases for details.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Java configuration file references the Database here:

[image]

So the “postgres” part in “jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres” of your configuration file refers to the red box I drew here in PostgreSQL/pgAdmin:

[image]

I suggest you create a new Database and move the schemas and tables you don’t want Hibernate to touch into that database.

As it is, every time hibernate connects to pgAdmin, it will access the database you set in your configuration file and the settings you have in your configuration file will apply to that database.

To create a new database in pgAdmin, right click on Databases and go to "New Database". Here is a picture:

[image]