# Unable to insert data into Redshift database in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, database, spring-boot, amazon-redshift

I have a Spring Boot application where I need to insert an object to a redshift table. No problem with manual insertion of data using a query. But I'm facing a challenge while persisting data to Amazon Redshift table from my Spring Boot app. Redshift table was created using the below query:

```
create table demand_test(id int not null identity(1,1), dateOfrequest DATE, country varchar(100), primary key(id))
```

So, I created a model class as shown below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "demand_test")
public class Demand implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private BigInteger id;

    @Column
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date dateofrequest;

    @Column
    private String country;


    public BigInteger getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(BigInteger id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getDateofrequest() {
        return dateofrequest;
    }

    public void setDateofrequest(Date dateofrequest) {
        this.dateofrequest = dateofrequest;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

}
```

When I try to insert `Demand` object, I get the below error:

```
com.amazon.support.exceptions.ErrorException: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: relation "demand_test_id_seq" does not exist;
    at com.amazon.redshift.client.messages.inbound.ErrorResponse.toErrorException(ErrorResponse.java:1830) ~[redshift-jdbc42-1.2.1.1001.jar:RedshiftJDBC_1.2.1.1001]
    at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGMessagingContext.handleErrorResponse(PGMessagingContext.java:822) ~[redshift-jdbc42-1.2.1.1001.jar:RedshiftJDBC_1.2.1.1001]
    at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGMessagingContext.handleMessage(PGMessagingContext.java:647) ~[redshift-jdbc42-1.2.1.1001.jar:RedshiftJDBC_1.2.1.1001]
```

I see a number of posts that are similar and were posted a couple of years back with no answers. I tried to filter out this issue to Hibernate specific, but I have no luck so far on this. I have been trying out  various options such as:

- using `GenerationType.AUTO`
- removing `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)`

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error with sequence since I'm using only `IDENTITY` generation type for the column.The `JpaRepository` `save()` method throws the mentioned error. What's going wrong here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sequence does not exist when it does - Postgres/Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44962937/sequence-does-not-exist-when-it-does-postgres-spring-boot)

Comment: @ŠimonKocúrek
I believe redshift doesnt support sequences even though it's postgresql based. Also, we didnt create sequence for the purpose. We're just using `IDENTITY` generation technique.

Comment: Rahul, could it be that the table was created before setting the ID to identity? In that case [recreating](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18342887/5521670) the schema might help.

Comment: I dropped the table and ran the above mentioned query to re-create it. Then I ran my app again. But I'm still getting the issue :(

Comment: Can you make sure you also have `<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect</property>` and `<property name="show_sql">true</property>` set, so that we can see what query is being sent?

Comment: These are the current configuration in `application.properties`:   `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none`, `spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver`.   No special mention of `dialect` there.

Comment: Can you change it then?

Comment: So, I can keep the above mentioned config and add `org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect=true` into the properties file right? Adding `create-drop` will delete my data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209831/discussion-between-rahul-raj-and-simon-kocurek).

Comment: @ŠimonKocúrek
I tried all your suggestions, but I'm still getting the same error. Note that updating object values are working. Persisting a new object is what not working.